# GroupBy peculiar behaviour

Tags: c#, linq

Why does Group by return all elements (in fact more than all, 8 elements in my case![enter image description here][1])

```
 List<Package> packages = new List<Package> { new Package { Company = "Coho Vineyard", Weight = 25.2, TrackingNumber = 10 },
                                             new Package { Company = "Lucerne Publishing", Weight = 18.7, TrackingNumber = 10},
                                             new Package { Company = "Wingtip Toys", Weight = 6.0, TrackingNumber = 12 },
                                             new Package { Company = "Contoso Pharmaceuticals", Weight = 9.3, TrackingNumber = 13},
                                             new Package { Company = "Wide World Importers", Weight = 33.8, TrackingNumber = 12 } };

IGrouping<long, Package>[] simba_3 = packages.GroupBy(x => 23L).ToArray();
```

simba_3 has one element with key = 23 and 8 Package elements , what is happening here?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not use `GroupBy` in a normal way:

```
List<Package> packages = new List<Package> { new Package { Company = "Coho Vineyard", Weight = 25.2, TrackingNumber = 10 },
                                             new Package { Company = "Lucerne Publishing", Weight = 18.7, TrackingNumber = 10},
                                             new Package { Company = "Wingtip Toys", Weight = 6.0, TrackingNumber = 12 },
                                             new Package { Company = "Contoso Pharmaceuticals", Weight = 9.3, TrackingNumber = 13},
                                             new Package { Company = "Wide World Importers", Weight = 33.8, TrackingNumber = 12 } };

var simba_3 = packages.GroupBy(x => x. Weight).ToArray();
var simba_4 = packages.GroupBy(x => x. TrackingNumber).ToArray();
```

Comment: No, No please refer to PetSerAl answer that's perfect, and that's the reason why it returned all the elements for a (so called) non-existing key